# Unix current time subtraction with fixed time

Tags: shell, unix

Requirement is to run the script after 4AM, the script is invoked at random time, so at the beginning of the script the below snippet is added:

```
while [ $(date +"%H%M%S") -lt 040000 ]
do
    curTime=$(date -u +"%H%M%S")
    reqTime=040000
    subTime=$(expr $reqTime - $curTime)
    if [ $cntTime -ge 0 ]
    then    
        sleep $cntTime
    fi
done
```

It checks if `curTime < 4AM`, if so, it subtracts curTime from 4AM, and sleeps for the reminder time(in seconds). But the subtraction isn't happening in seconds, it is numeric.

Comment: Do you know about the `at` and `cron` daemons, which are designed for running things at specified times?

Comment: They are unix schedulers. 
In my case scheduling is happening at different level, the script is invoked by a different job. So, I cant use cron here.

Answer (score 0):

If you use bash and GNU/Linux,

```
echo $((`date +%s` - `date -d 'today 04:00' +%s`))
```

gives you the seconds since 04:00 the same day.